# Old movie about three boys who make a computer that lets them create a force field that leads them into space

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

So I'm trying to think of a movie I saw once when I was a kid. I don't know when the movie was originally published but I do know what it was about. The general plot was three boys come together and end up building a computer which allows them to go into space via some type of weird force field bubble. Thing I remember one boy had a father who worked with computers I think, and one boy said he never had dreams before. Does anybody know what movie I'm talking about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might this be [Explorers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explorers_(film))?

> Ben Crandall is a young teen living in the suburbs of Washington DC who experiences vivid dreams about flying through clouds and over a vast, city-like circuit board...usually after falling asleep watching old sci-fi films (The War of the Worlds is a favorite). Every night, upon waking from the dream, he draws the circuit board. Ben shows the sketches to his friend, child prodigy Wolfgang Muller. At school, Ben develops a crush on Lori Swenson - but he isn't sure whether it's mutual. Both boys meet punkish-but-likable Darren Woods, with whom they share their circuit board-concepts. Wolfgang builds an actual microchip based on Ben's drawings. The chip enables the generation of an electromagnetic bubble which surrounds a pre-determined area. As the boys discover, the bubble is capable of moving at near-limitless distances and speeds without the usual ill-effects from inertia. They construct a rudimentary spacecraft out of an abandoned tilt-a-whirl car; they name their ship the Thunder Road, after Bruce Springsteen's song of the same title. Their experiments with the Thunder Road draw attention from the US Government, which sends agents to scout the area for unidentified flying objects.

It has

- Force field bubbles that move through space.
- Three boys as the protagonists.
- Dreams sent by aliens.

I can't find confirmation or denial of a father who worked with computers.

It was released in 1985.

Comment: this has been bugging me for years I'm glad I discovered this site I'm glad you could help me find it